# Doubt in Poynting's theorem

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, energy-conservation, poynting-vector

In Griffiths's Electrodynamics, to explain Poynting's theorem, he writes:

> Suppose we have some charge and current configuration which at time *t* produces fields **E** and **B**. In the next instant *dt* the charges move around a bit. How much work *dW* is done by the electromagnetic forces acting on the charges in this time interval? Now according to Lorentz Force law the work done on a charge q is:
> $$dW= \mathbf F\cdot\mathbf {dl} = q( \mathbf E + \mathbf {v\ x} \mathbf B)\cdot \mathbf v dt = q \mathbf E\cdot\mathbf v dt.$$

(Till here, I understand what he's saying. Then he generalized this for charge distributions saying)

> In terms of the charge distributions and current densities, q goes to $\rho d\tau$ and $\rho \mathbf v$ becomes $\mathbf J$, so the rate at which work is done on all the charges in a volume is.
> $$ dW/dt = \int_V (\mathbf {E\cdot J})  d\tau.$$

NOW, he starts writing this current density $\mathbf J$ in terms of magnetic field using Ampere-Maxwell law to eliminate  it as:

> $$\mathbf {E.J} = (1/\mu_0) (\mathbf {E\cdot(\nabla x B)}  - (\mathbf {\epsilon_0 E\cdot\partial E/ \partial t}).$$

And concludes that this magnetic field $\mathbf B$ is the total magnetic field of our system but we derived it from only the one charge distribution. So isn't $\mathbf B$ the magnetic field coming only from that charge distribution! Please help.

Comment: $\vec{B}$ is the overall magnetic field (not only the one caused from the charge moving), because of that, Maxwells law (Biot-Savart, if you want) is applicable. 
The explanation doesn't use the fact that the magnetic field might stem only from the charge (or the charge distribution) that we look at in that moment. Because of that, there is no problem.

Comment: Just to say the previous comment is correct. The $\bf B$ appearing in all the equations you have quoted is the total $\bf B$ field at each point in space. The question of which movement of charge or permanent dipole may be the source of that $\bf B$ does not arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question relates to the mysterious nature of most differential equations (DE). Though, the DE has only the local source appeared in the equation, its solution nerverthless collects all effects from the whole source distribution, via the boundary connection to the vicinal cells.

It is easy to illustrate using Poisson's eqution:

$$
   \nabla^2 \Phi(\vec{r}) =-\vec{ \nabla} \cdot \vec{E} = -4\pi\rho(\vec{r}).
$$

In its differential form, potential $ \Phi(\vec{r})$ is only related to the local charge, but the solution includes effects of all charges.

$$
\Phi(\vec{r}) =\int\int\int_{\Omega(\vec{r}')}\frac{k_e \rho(\vec{r}') d^3\vec{r}'}{|\vec{r}'-\vec{r}|}
$$

Therefore, it is ok to replace the local charge $\rho(\vec{r})$ by $\vec{ \nabla} \cdot \vec{E} $